# Before After Image Slider set up Divi, WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have my before img slider. I tried to paste in code, but then my page going to mad although the slider works.

[image]

**Original**

[image]

**My Slider**

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GIJD6V38V0QR

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    height: 73.5vw;
    margin: 1vw auto;
    max-height: 750px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 98vw;
  }
  
  .container figure {
    background-image: url(https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/1st.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #compare {
    background-image: url(https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/2nd.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 10px 0 15px -13px #000;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 98.6%;
    min-width: 0.6%;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    animation: first 2s 1 normal ease-in-out 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation: first 2s 1 normal ease-in-out 0.1s;
  }
  
  input#slider {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: col-resize;
    height: 100vw;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -100vw;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  input#slider::-moz-range-track {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  input#slider::-ms-track {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100vw;
    left: 0;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -100vw;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: col-resize;
    color: transparent;
  }
  
  input#slider::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  input#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 100vw;
    width: 0.5%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  input#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 100vw;
    width: 0.5%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  input#slider::-ms-thumb {
    height: 100vw;
    width: 0.5%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  input#slider::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #compare::before {
    background: url(https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/comparision.png) no-repeat scroll 0 center transparent;
    background-size: contain;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -34px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 64px;
  }
  
  @keyframes first {
    0% {
      width: 0%;
    }
    50% {
      width: 80%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes first {
    0% {
      width: 0%;
    }
    50% {
      width: 80%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
</style>
<script>
  function beforeAfter() {
    document.getElementById('compare').style.width = document.getElementById('slider').value + "%";
  }
</script>


<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <figure>
      <div id="compare"></div>
    </figure>
    <input oninput="beforeAfter()" onchange="beforeAfter()" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" />
  </div>
  <script src="function.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't find the problem with `style`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are trying to paste that code to the Divi builder there will be a problem. You need to find out their way of inserting the codes. Please contact Divi support.

Comment: They will say "buy divi plugin for this img", my slider https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GI7TREPS8JY8 works fine, but this slider very simple, and with mobile not sliding..